# Solving $ \frac{x+1}{2-x}\; < \frac{x}{3+x}$ stepwise

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I need help in solving this inequality stepwise:
$$ \frac{x+1}{2-x}\; < \frac{x}{3+x}$$
I am solving the problems in the book *The Calculus with Analytical Geometry* by Louis Leithold.

Comment: OK; what do you know about solving inequalities? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that when there is x in denominator, then we have to consider both positive and negative values of it. But I am stuck on how to apply that, that's why I need a step by step solution.

Comment: Points where one or both sides do not exist: $x=2, x=-3$.  So consider three cases: $x<-3$; $-3 < x < 2$; and $x>2$.  Include your work in the question; otherwise the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you show your work on the problem. You'll find that "Solve this for me" questions are poorly received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight addition to the answer provided by Parth Sachdeva:

What Parth has used to arrive at the answer is the ***"Wavy Curve Method"***.

It involves the following steps:

1. Factor the polynomials.
2. Make the coefficient of the variable of all factors positive.
3. Multiply/divide both sides of the inequality by $-1$ to remove the minus sign.
4. Find the roots and asymptotes of the inequality by equating each factor to $0$.
5. Plot the points on a number line and start with the largest factor. Here the curve from the positive region of the number line should intersect that point. Now look at the power of that factor and if it's odd, then we have to change the path of the curve from their respective roots while if it's even continue in the same region.

Parth has already shown all the steps till the Step $4$ (along with the step $0$ where he took RHS to LHS). Here's how step $5$ will look after we have obtained our critical points as $-3$ and $2$ (note that $2x^2+2x+3$ gives non-real solutions for $x$):

[image: Wavy curve]

Since we are interested in solutions where $f(x)>0$ so, that'd be the region except that from $-3$ to $2$.

Thus, $x\in (−∞,−3)U(2,∞) $

If you're interested in knowing more about the **Wavy Curve Method** then check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKRYf4UemaI) to know its application and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HwFttjpeuA) to know the logic behind this method.

Answer (score 2):

See first take RHS to LHS
$$\frac{x+1}{2-x}-\frac{x}{3+x}<0$$

Take LCM and CROSS MULTIPLY

$$\frac{(x^2+4x+3)-(x)(2-x)}{(2-x)(3+x)}<0$$

$$\frac{2x^2+2x+3}{(2-x)(3+x)}<0$$

$$\frac{2x^2+2x+3}{(x-2)(3+x)}>0$$

As numerator is always positive
Critical points are -3,2

Thus ans would be $x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup(2,\infty) $